# Crontab is not starting automatically after Docker Container reboot

Tags: cron, docker, autostart

I have running a docker container in the qnap container station.
Docker Container OS: Ubuntu 20

I have installed crontab on this Container. The Container will restarted every day.

The problem now is, after the Container is restarted, cron is not running!
So how can i add the "service cron start" to autorun after system reboot?

Thank you

Comment: Some QNAP devices support LXC containers, can you use those instead? LXC containers boot like a regular system, with services and all, so cron and other services work perfectly there.

Comment: LXC is not supported after Container Station 3 at QNAP. Is there also a work around to start cron after reboot?